# Combine multiple edcf graphs in one: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to show cumulative proportion of a column variable (e.g., mpg) by color (fcyl) and one without any color. This is different from using cowplot or patchwork to show them side-by-side. I specifically want them to be shown together.

Here's an example:

```r
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, fcyl = factor(cyl, levels = c("4","6","8"), 
                                       labels = c("4 cycles", "6 cycles", "8 cycles")))

mtcars %>% filter(fcyl %in% c("4 cycles", "6 cycles")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, color = fcyl)) + stat_ecdf(size=2) 
#This graph shows cumulative proportion of mpg by 4 and 6 cycles of 'fcyl' 

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) + stat_ecdf(size=2) #This one is total cumulative density proportion
```

I tried adding a `stat_edcf` to the first plot and its possible to do this for all three factors in fcyl but not the two specific ones.

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) + stat_ecdf(size=2) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = mpg, color = fcyl), size=2) #This works

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) + stat_ecdf(size=2) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = mpg, color = filter(mtcars, fcyl %in% c("4 cycles", "6 cycles")), size=2))

#This does not work.
```

How do I show them in one graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new layer:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  filter(fcyl %in% c("4 cycles", "6 cycles")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) + 
  stat_ecdf(size = 2, aes(color = 'total')) +
  stat_ecdf(size = 2, aes(color = fcyl)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: But if you filter before, than how will the total contain all the data? Fcyl has 3 factors. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you wanted. You can simply pass the unfiltered data as a `data` argument to the black layer: change that line to `stat_ecdf(size = 2, aes(color = 'total'), data = mtcars) +`